# FlexibleJDBCRealm and Digest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

I have this working in Glassfish, and if I do not hash my passwords (so they are plain text) it works fine.

But, if I try to use hashing, I can't get it to work. In my Java code, when I create a new user, I hash the password like this (using the defaults for charset encoding)

```
    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");                    
    byte[] hashedPassword = md5.digest(password.getBytes());
    return new String(hashedPassword);
```

And in the properties for the realm I set the "password.digest" property to MD5.

Note, I'll be using SHA-512 in reality but am trying MD5 for simplicity, since it's mentioned in the docs for FlexibleJDBCRealm.

Any ideas? Thanks

PS is there is a more 'official' version of this kind of realm included with Java nowadays? It would be great if FlexibleJDBCRealm (or similar) was built-in to Java EE at some point.

Comment: What is not working, precisely?

Comment: It's just not letting me log in with a user whose password is hashed. So I'm guessing there is a slight difference between the way I am hashing it and the hash that FlexibleJDBCRealm is coming up with. I'm using the standard algorithm names in both my code and FJDBCR's properties though, so I can't think what else would be different.

Comment: Have you experimented with using charsets other than the default in your code? Both in the call to `getBytes()` and `new String()`? Just clutching at straws I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good strategy that I have also been using :) Yeah, I have played around with that a bit (forcing them both to UTF-8 for example). I'll experiment more tonight, but thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing two things wrong:

I was not consistently using charset encoding. I now use Charset.defaultCharset().name() which is also the default used by FJDBCR:

```
MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");                    
byte[] digestedPassword = sha.digest(password.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset().name()));
return new String(digestedPassword, Charset.defaultCharset().name());
```

Note it is used in BOTH the second and third lines in the above code.

I was also not setting the password.encoding property (assuming TEXT would be used as the default).

All works now. Just going to add a seed next, and use SHA-512 and I should be up and running